# Logging in automatically without removing the password

Tags: security, password, login, screen-sharing

Is there any way to have OSX log in automatically in a certain account when starting up, without asking for the password, while preventing remote (or even local network) connections without password?

I have a computer that I use both as a home server and a media center, so it has to be accessible from outside world in a secure manner (SSH + Screen Sharing), but at the same time I don't want to key in the passwords every time my media center boots up, or more importantly each time it wakes up from sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. An **automatic login** option is available within the System Preferences.

**System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Automatic login**

This ability may not be available if you are using FileVault.

When setting up this option, you will need to provide the user's password. See [Does activating auto-login compromise secure password storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50652) for a discussion about how this feature works.

[image: System Preferences on OS X]

Comment: Ah, the problem was File Vault. Thanks for mentioning that. I don't have any critical file on that computer per se, so I removed File Vault encryption and it worked.